# Spring MVC and WML web page?

Tags: spring, wml

is it possible to contruct and use a WML page instead of a normal html page to render my views that contain a form?

i could not find any examples on how to achieve this and i could not even find the "form" tag in WML. Instead, from my understanding WML, uses cards with input tags to process a form of some sort but in Spring mvc's SimpleFormController it is used in conjunction to a html form not a WML input card.

Answer (score 0):

Spring MVC's controller infrastructure doesn't care if the page is rendered in HTML or WML.  Both HTML forms and WML cards end up generating HTTP requests when submitted, and the controller can't tell the difference.

However, Spring only provides an HTML form tag library, so if you want to generate WML, you'll have to do it all yourself.

Is this really something you want to get into, though? WML is obsolete, and only very old phones need it.

Comment: No i really dont want to get into WML stuff as its a dead end technology but the client's requirements are based on old j2me devices :(

Comment: @jonney: I fell your pain. `<card>` it is, then.